# Opening uploaded file in google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I upload and try to open the file using the below code, I am getting this error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

My code is as follows:

```
from google.colab import files

#upload file
uploaded = files.upload() 

# Open file
f = open(uploaded['small.txt'], 'r')

# Feed the file text into findall(); it returns a list of all the found strings
strings = re.findall(r'ne\w', f.read())
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Error is on line 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
f = open(uploaded['small.txt'], 'r')
```

When you upload a file using `uploaded = files.upload()`, the actual file contents are stored in `uploaded['small.txt']`, not the path.

So, I believe it should fix the error to simply use `uploaded['small.txt']` directly in the regexp, e.g.,

```
strings = re.findall(r'ne\w', uploaded['small.txt'])
```

Comment: Many people are confused by this. Most of them expect an "uploaded" file to really exists there in the current folder.

Is there a reason why it's not implemented as what people expected?
Is there a security reason or some other hidden reasons?